# Can I re-download my '.profile' file on ubuntu or should I restart?

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox

Some context: I'm taking a computer science class and we're supposed to set up some virtual machines that use Linux to do some coding. I'm using VirtualBox for the virtual machines, along with Ubuntu. I've been following my professor's steps to set up the machine, along with some specific customizations for him.

We were supposed to install this script into our '.profile' file, but running into some screen issues, I decided to close the terminal in Ubuntu and restart the process. After restarting, the terminal warned me of multiple files being worked on, so I ended up deleting both '.profile' files in order to start afresh. Only, I didn't realize I also deleted my original profile as well, I think. I think I can still install the script, but wanted to know whether this would cause further issues down the line, and whether I can download the file again. If not, setting up another machine from scratch is not hard work, but slightly annoying.

Bit of a rookie to Ubuntu and Linux in general, if anyone has some advice or tips, would appreciate the same a lot.

EDIT: Comments have asked about the version of Ubuntu I'm using, I should've added that. I'm using the LTS version, version 22.04.3. I've been a bit dumbfounded how I managed to do what I did so been a bit distracted, apologies. I've also added a screenshot below of what my terminal looks like currently, the command line used to be green, now it's white.

[image: screenshot of ubuntu terminal]

Comment: If the VM is only for a class, I would delete and make another VM to avoid deviating from the professor's instructions

Comment: One of the great things about VMs is that you can take snapshots at will. Next time before you make major changes, take a snapshot.